# How to update data when input is drop down?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am so new in html, php, javascript, mysql. i created a drop down menu using java script that contains a list of 2011 to 2510. During update i can not display the stored value that is generated using java script. I searched but found nothing. A portion of code.....

```
<select name="eca">
            <option id="eca" required="required" class="ecadetail" value="NSS" <?php if ($eca == 'NSS') echo 'selected="selected"';?>">NSS</option>
            <option id="eca" required="required" class="ecadetail" value="NCC" <?php if ($eca == 'NCC') echo 'selected="selected"';?>">NCC</option>
            <option id="eca" required="required" class="ecadetail" value="Cultural" <?php if ($eca == 'Cultural') echo 'selected="selected"';?>">Cultural</option>
            </select>
        </div>      
        <div class="label">Year</div>
        <div class="inputyear">
            <select name="years" >
                <script language="JavaScript">
                 // loop to create the list
                     var year = 2010
                     for (var i=1; i <=500; i++)
                    {
                        year++;
                        document.write("<option>" + year + "</option>");
                    }
                    // end JS code hide -->
                    <option  value="<?php if ($year == 'year') echo 'selected="selected"';?>"></script>
                </script>
            </select>
        </div>              
    </div> <!-- end of 7th row -->
```

the value for eca is working fine. The value year is stored in $year.
help please...

Comment: Please explain better what you want to do. Were do you want to show the value of the dropdown?

Comment: field name is years...

Comment: @sergio.. Whatever the value stored in database i want to display in the field specified by 'years'.

Comment: @sergio..I got your question..Actually i want to display in drop down menu onle..The value should be selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop can purely done in php then why involving the javascript

```
<select name="years" >

<?php 
 $matchyear = 2010;
for ($i=2010; $i <=2510; $i++)
{ ?>
<option  value="<?php echo $i;?>" <?php if ($i== $matchyear) echo 'selected="selected"';?>><?php echo $i;?> </option>   
<?php }

?>

</select>
```

Make things easier for you not a complex programming so that other person can understand easily and call you by good names

Comment: @dianuj...your ans is correct but we need to replace <option  value="<?php echo $i;?>" <?php if ($i== $matchyear) echo 'selected="selected"';?>><?php echo $i;?> </option>  by <option  value="<?php echo $i;?>" <?php if ($year == $i) echo 'selected="selected"';?>><?php echo $year;?> </option>

Comment: @Jahaan as you wish dear i have just given you the idea